# Survey Question Reordering?

Tags: javascript

Im doing a survey application . It is having option to add questions.If on clicks on add button it will show the text box for adding question and a select box for selecting question type(radio button , check box) once it fill the field  i will store than in database ans display in UI. then the user have option for adding question above and below. if he add question above i need to reorder the question number below. if he add question in middle i need to update the question number below that. how can i solve this situation ?

Answer (score 0):

In a similar situation, I have shown the list of items to be sorted in a table/grid and given the option to the user to move up or down the items in the grid as per their choice. I kept a column for order in the grid (hidden in my case) and a corresponding column in the database table. Whenever there is a reordering in the grid, I update the order by a swap operation for the two rows that are swapping position. So, once the user has done the reordering and save the order using a button, I use to update the order column according to the order in the front page.

Answer (score 0):

https://pixbyfunc.appspot.com/pub/asq/asq.html is a running example of a contingent questionnaire. A different set of questions are presented based on if the user likes wine or not.

It's designed using JavaScript that looks like:

```
Q().ask("Have you had your drink today?");

Q('like-wine').using('radio', 'Yes', 'No').ask("Do you like wine?");

Q('like-wine').matches('no').naming('reason').using('textarea').ask("Why not?").abort();//stop the survey

Q().ask("How much do you drink a day?");

Q('which-wine').using('checkbox', 'Reds', 'Whites', 'Other').ask("What do you like?");
Q('which-wine').matches('reds').ask("If you would like to receive a free bottle of Chateau d'Yquem Sauternes 2004 from your Santa, please provide your email.");

Q().start();
```

You can view the source to see how Q is implemented and to modify to suit your needs.